# If $\| f \|_p \leq 1$, then $|f(x)| \leq 1$ for some $x$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $p \in [1,\infty)$ and $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $\|f\|_p \leq 1$. Then there is a $x\in [0,1]$ such that $|f(x)| \leq 1$.

This statement seems completely obvious, but I haven't been able to prove it. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If not, then $|f(x)| > 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Hence $\|f\|_p > 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: why is $\|f\|_p > 1$ ?

Comment: $\int_0^1 |f|^p > \int_0^1 dx =1$.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas Since $|f(x)| > 1$ for all $x$, $|f(x)|^p > 1$ for all $x$ (since $p\in [1,\infty))$. Therefore $\int_0^1 |f(x)|^p\, dx > \int_0^1 1\, dx = 1$, i.e., $\|f\|_p^p > 1$. Hence $\|f\|_p > 1$.

Comment: @kobe: If $f>g$ then in general $\int f\geq \int g$. The pointwise consideration is not taking in to account any properties of the measure and the integration depends on the measure. I guess his question is how do you conclude here that the inequality is strict with the integrals? Might be trivial in the case of Lebesgue measure, but what is the argument?

Comment: @ThomasE. if $\|f\|_p = 1$, then $\int_0^1 (|f(x)|^p - 1)\, dx = 0$, so $|f(x)|^p - 1 = 0$ for almost every $x \in [0,1]$. Then $|f(x)| = 1$ for almost every $x$. This contradicts the assumption that $|f(x)| > 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @ThomasE.: Swept under the rug here is a lemma: "If $g \ge 0$ almost everywhere and $\int g = 0$ then $g = 0$ almost everywhere".  It's true for any measure $\mu$.  To prove it, let $A_n = \{x : g(x) \ge 1/n\}$.  Then $\int g \ge \frac{1}{n} \mu(A_n)$, so we must have $\mu(A_n) = 0$.  But $A = \{x : g(x) > 0\}$ is the union of the sets $A_n$ so by countable additivity $\mu(A) = 0$.

Comment: @NateEldredge exactly, thank you. But your $\mu$ is a positive measure here?

Comment: Yes, by "measure" I mean "positive measure".  The lemma is obviously false for signed or complex measures.

Comment: Yeah, that would do the job.